# Odd equality result with a HashSet of an Enum type?

Tags: c#, equality, hashset

I have two hash sets that I've constructed in different ways that contain all the enum values.

```
    setWithAllEnums.Equals(setToTest); //  Returns false

    !(setWithAllEnums.Except(setToTest).Any());  //  Returns True
```

Why are these not equivalent?  Does .NET not provide a GetHashCode for Enums?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`HashSet<T>` doesn't override `Equals`. Even if two hash sets contain exactly the same values they are still unequal if they refer to different objects. The method you want is `SetEquals`.

Tim Schmelter makes an excellent point though. `x.SetEquals(y)` and `!x.Except(y).Any()` are not the same thing either. The sets x = `{1, 2}` and y = `{1, 2, 3}` are not equal, but `!x.Except(y).Any()` is true.  `x.SetEquals(y)` is equivalent to `!x.Except(y).Any() && !y.Except(x).Any()`.

Comment: @ReedCopsey: Your claim in your deleted comment to your deleted answer that hash sets proffer up their contents in a sorted order is false. Try it. `var s1 = new HashSet<string>() { "X", "Y" }; var s2 = new HashSet<string>() { "Y", "X" }; Console.WriteLine(s1.SequenceEqual(s2));`  This produces false.  Hash sets in practice produce the items *in the order they were added*. Note that they are not *guaranteed* to do that; it is an undocumented implementation detail and subject to change.

Comment: I glossed over SetEquals thinking it was a setter. Thanks!